# What is a difference between 1 instance EC2 m3.2xlarge and 2 instances m3.xlarge

Tags: amazon-ec2, devops

I have a web app, currently I installed it on EC2 with 4 instances of m3.xlarge. What is a difference if I installed it on 2 instances of m3.2xlarge? Which one is better? Could somebody please help me explain this?

Comment: What do you mean 'better' here?

Comment: System services doesn't works as 1 + 1 = 2. 
It works as in combination of CPU processing, Memory usage, disk I/O. 
Because splitting system will produce some overhead. OS itself will take up some memory and CPU scheduling processing. Be more specific on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 m3 family includes the M3 instance types and provides a balance of compute, memory, and network resources

Model-------------vCPU-------Mem(GB)--------SSD Storage(GB)
 m3.xlarge---------4------------15------------------2 x 40
 m3.2xlarge--------8------------30-----------------2 x 80

4 instances of m3.xlarge similar to  2 instances of m3.2xlarge
But it depend on the web app you host (redundancy, How good you application running with shared resources etc)

Comment: Thanks for your response quickly. So if I installed my app with 2 instances m3.2xlarge, so my web app runs faster than 4 instances m3.xlarge, right? Or the same?

Comment: If you have replicated database setup and load balanced app setup then, or the clustered database architecture then better with the same setup, but need to think about the load as well, otherwise 2 instances m3.2xlarge is sufficient, same performance can be obtained instead of 4  instances m3.xlarge

Answer (score 0):

4x m3.xlarge:

- More redundancy (security)
- depending on your environment, you can save cost by shutting down some of the servers during the night or week end for example when you know there is less activity (of course if this is for PRODUCTION, you CAN'T do that)
- Easier for maintenance (you can make maintenance on one server without being at risk on unavailability

2x m3.2xlarge:

- Easier to maintain / monitor
- Depending on your code and datas, you can have better performence

Both choices are good, but the best choice will mostly depend on your needs ... Do you need to be 24/24-7/7? how do you plan to update your app (deployments)? what kind of activity ... etc..

Hope it helps.